# Convert object to Json-formatted string in Jscript .Net

Tags: fiddler, jscript.net

In Fiddler, I have a response body (application/json) that I convert into an Object using `eval()` (if there is a better way please let me know) to perform some checks. Now I want to convert several parts (but not all parts) of the object back into a string and save them to seperate files. How would I do this in Jscript?

I have tried using the `ToString()` method but it only returns `[object Object]`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and I asked Fiddler Forum [about it](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-use-fiddler-webformats-json-jsondecode). 
From the answer, I cooked this FiddlerScript (JScript) to answer yours:

```
var sInput = '{"a" : 1, "b" : [2, 3, 4]}';
var oJSON = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode(sInput);
FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat('input: {0}', sInput);
FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat('oJSON: {0}', oJSON.ToString());
FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat('oJSON["a"]: {0} (expected: 1)', oJSON.JSONObject["a"]);
FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat('oJSON["b"] : {0} (expected: 2)', oJSON.JSONObject["b"][0]);
```

I hope this will help after half a year...

Answer (score 2):

JScript.NET does not itself include a JSON serializer.

You can either use one from the appropriate .NET assembly, or you can use the JSON serializer baked into Fiddler; have a look at the `Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonEncode(object)` function.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. `Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonEncode(object)` returns an empty string when used on an object like `var oTest: Object = {"a":"b"};`

Comment: What *exactly* did you pass in to the function? Generally, you'd want to pass the value of `oSesssion.GetResponseBodyAsString()` into `JSON.JsonDecode(string)` rather than having JScript.NET perform its own `eval()`.

Comment: Yes that is what I pass in. Doing this `var oTest = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode(oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString());`
`var sTest = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonEncode(oTest);` returns an empty string on a simple test page I set up.

Comment: @EricLaw When I use the above code in my FiddlerScript, I get the following error: Type 'Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode could not be found, is an assembly reference missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you running the latest build of Fiddler?